# A complete list of rated hotels in Turkey

Tags: hotels, turkey

I have reached an area of Turkey where hotels are few and far between, which is making it more challenging to plan my trip. I am therefore looking for new ways to find suitably located accommodation to help me plan.

Is there any comprehensive online list/database of all hotels which have been awarded with star ratings by the Turkish Ministry of Tourism? (Preferably it would include the province in which each hotel is located so I can filter them depending on where I am).

Comment: Aren't the usual tools like Google Maps or the many hotel booking websites suitable?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://tga.gov.tr/search-hotel-category-en/

Comment: I second jcaron here. I doubt that there are many hotels, which can't be found on Google Maps. I would also at least assume that there are many smaller hotels, which have no official star rating and will be missing in the data you are asking for.

Answer (score 12):

I'm local, and yes, there *is* such a website of Türkiye Ministry of Culture and Tourism.

https://ktb.gov.tr/genel/searchhotel.aspx?lang=en

You can filter them by their name, city, district, status and certificate type. Unfortunately, no star filter on that one.

[image]

But there is another website (which also belongs to Türkiye Ministry of Culture and Tourism) that you can filter by their star rating (column called "Tesis Sınıfı") as well (there is no English support for that one, use Google Translate)

https://yigm.ktb.gov.tr/genel/turizmtesisleri.aspx

[image]

Comment: Both sites you are linking to seem to only offer a rather small selection of cities to search in. How could I use any of the sites to e.g. find a hotel in Lüleburgaz?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Lüleburgaz is a district of Kırklareli. You have to filter Kırklareli as a city and then you can filter Lüleburgaz as a district. You may _not_ find all of them of course. Searching on Google maps can be a better alternative in such a case.

Comment: Basically, "just use Google Maps" because it's more accurate than government sources.